# Moving a user to the message author's voice channel

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Trying to make my discord bot move a user to the voice channel that the message author is in. E.g. I write `!move @john` Then the bot would move "john" to my voice channel.

```
# command to move a user to current channel
@bot.command()
async def move(ctx,member:discord.Member=None):
    channel= discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.voice_channels)
    if not member:
        await ctx.send("Who am I trying to move? Use !move @user")
    await member.move_to(channel)
```

At the moment it moves the users, but only to the first voice channel in the server. How do I get it to move it to the author's voice channel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `VoiceChannel` the author is in is stored in `ctx.author.voice.channel`.  Notably, `.voice` and `.channel` can be `None`, so we need check for that

```
@bot.command()
async def move(ctx,member:discord.Member=None):
    if ctx.author.voice and ctx.author.voice.channel:
        channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    else:
        await ctx.send("You are not connected to voice!")
    if not member:
        await ctx.send("Who am I trying to move? Use !move @user")
    await member.move_to(channel)
```